# How to split a string into parts to populate a dict in a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of files I need to draw information from and I want to populate a dict with it. I know how to extract the information with a regular expression but the dict part mystifies me.

**Code**

```
import re

mylist = ['anna01','bobby03','dean120']
mydict = {}
```

**Intended result**

mydict = {'anna01': 1, 'bobby03':3, 'dean120':120}

The regex I use in the actual problem is :

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.bmp'):
        image_name = file
        files.append(os.path.join(path, file))
        print(os.path.join(path, file))
        print(get_burst_from_name(file))
        print(image_name)
        pattern = '_\d*%'
        result = re.findall(pattern, file)[0]
        result = result.replace("_","")
        duty = result.replace("%","")
        print('duty=', duty)
```

where the key for a dict would be 'file' and the value would be 'duty'

Comment: did you try anything? can you show us?

Comment: could you please edit it into the question?

Comment: that's from a more complicated string than in the question but it works, in this case duty being the 'value' and 'file' being the key.

Comment: @Windy71 As you said you know how to extract the number from the string, this code should work: `my_dict = {x:_get_num(x) for x in myList}`. _get_num is your code that extract the number/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll get your desired output.

```
import re
mylist = ['anna01','bobby03','dean120']
mydict = {}
for i in mylist:
    key = str(re.findall("\D+", i)[0])
    val = int(re.findall("\d+", i)[0])
    mydict[key] = val    
print("mydict = {}".format(mydict))
```

Output

```
mydict = {'anna': 1, 'bobby': 3, 'dean': 120}
```

Comment: Thank you Kitto, it was the mydict[key] = val line that for some reason I couldn't get (bashes face into desk)

Answer (score 3):

i think maybe this little code will help you:

```
import re
mylist = ['anna01','bobby03','dean120']
myDict = {}
pattern = '(?P<Name>[^\d]+)(?P<Number>\d+)'
for index,value in enumerate(mylist):
    searchedRegex = re.search(pattern , value)
    if searchedRegex:
        number = searchedRegex.group("Number")
        myDict[value] = int(number)
print(myDict)
```

**Output**

```
{'anna01': 1, 'bobby03': 3, 'dean120': 120}
```

Exactly as you called.

And if you just want to have their names(without number), then you can use `group("Name")` as i prepared it in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = ['anna01','bobby03','dean120']
mydict = {}

for i in mylist:
    word = ''
    num = ''
    for j in i:
        if j.isalpha():
            word += j
        else:
            num += j
    if num[0] == '0':
        num = num[1:]

    mydict[word] = int(num)

print(mydict)
```

**Result**

```
{'dean': 120, 'anna': 1, 'bobby': 3}
```